# how to persist sessions in httpx python

Tags: python, python-requests, httpx

We can easily create a persistent session using:

```
s = requests.Session()
```

But how to achieve this using httpx library?

```
async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(
            URL,
            params=params,
        )
```

Comment: https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
with httpx.Client() as client:

    r = client.get('https://example.com')
```

Source https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/

Comment: OP wants async session i think.

Answer (score 1):

Just dont use the context manager.

```
client = httpx.AsyncClient()
response = await client.get(
    URL,
    params=params,
)
```

Or if you want to have the same cleanup functionality:

```
client = httpx.AsyncClient()
try:
    response = await client.get(
        URL,
        params=params,
    )
    # do other stuff
finally:
    await client.aclose()
```